# JPA @SecondaryTables, why my primary table is empty? While the secondary tables is not empty?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I've simple POJO like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_address")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="t_city"),
    @SecondaryTable(name="t_country")
})
public class Address{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String street1;

private String street2;

@Column(table="t_city")
private String city;

@Column(table="t_city")
private String state;

@Column(table="t_city")
private String zipcode;

@Column(table="t_country")
private String country;

// setter - getter
}
```

And then in my Main class, i've an instance like :

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setStreet1("boulevard of broken dream");
address.setStreet2("abbey road");
address.setCity("San Fransisco");
address.setState("California");
address.setZipcode("13460");
address.setCountry("USA");

// some variable declaration

tx.begin();
em.persist(address);
tx.commit();
```

After execute the Main class, i've 3 tables inside the database there are:

- t_address [ID,STREET1,STREET2]
- t_city [ID, CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE]
- t_country [ID,COUNTRY]

After query every table, why the data only store in t_city and t_country, NOT in t_address? Can you explain the reason?

Comment: I saw the same example in a book.  Maybe you could try using a different database to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just tried your code example in my environment using three different JPA providers: Hibernate 3.6, EclipseLink 2.1 and OpenJPA 2.1 with MySQL 5.0 and they all succeeded. The only difference I saw is that OpenJPA forced me to declare the pkJoinColumns in the seconday table annotation. Are you seeing any exceptions in the application logs?

Comment: @edalorzo and @toto yes first i'try using Derby, but after switch to MySQL everything look OK, doesn't know what the problem is. Thanks for your comment.